# How do i call webservice from windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a windows service from which I am trying to call a method under remote webservice but I am getting error that "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'MyWebService.BookingCitySoap' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element."

Following is the code for that

.cs File

```
MyWebService.BookingCitySoapClient ws = new MyWebService.BookingCitySoapClient();

                ws.CallBookStatus();

                ws.CallCanStatus();
```

App.config

```
<bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BookingCitySoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:51317/Web/BookingCity.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BookingCitySoap"
            contract="MyWebService.BookingCitySoap" name="BookingCitySoap" />
    </client>
```

Comment: are you sure your app.config gets deployed when you install the service?

Comment: I think you have added service reference, try to add web reference as it is asmx service.

Comment: A windows service can't consume asmx, you must deploy it as WCF